# How to only target the ul li:nth-child(2) in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors

I am trying to make only the `li:nth-child(2)` width animate from `230px` to `780px`.

I have done this, but now whenever there is a `li` within this section it then gives the `nth-child(3)` that width of `780px` also.

How do I only affect the width of the one element I am trying to?

**JS :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getsocial").live('click', function(){
        $(".homepage li:nth-child(1)").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".homepage li:nth-child(3)").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".homepage ul > li:nth-child(2)").fadeOut(1000).delay(300).fadeIn(1000).animate({width:'780px'},1000);
        $(".socialshare").hide().delay(2400).fadeIn(1000);
        $(".goback").hide().delay(2400).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

I have also tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getsocial").live('click', function(){
        $(".homepage li:nth-child(1)").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".homepage li:nth-child(3)").fadeOut(1000);
        $(".homepage li:nth-child(2)").fadeOut(1000).delay(300).fadeIn(1000).animate({width:'780px'},1000);
        $(".socialshare").hide().delay(2400).fadeIn(1000);
        $(".goback").hide().delay(2400).fadeIn(1000);
    });
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="homepage">
  <ul>
    <li>content here</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>content here</li>
        <li>content here</li>
        <li>content here</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>content here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for the help given :)

Comment: Maybe `".homepage > ul > li:nth-child(2)"`? It really is not clear what you are trying to do. Can you be more specific? Which of the two `ul`s do you want to target?

Comment: @Jon Basically i am enlarging the home page ul li:nth-child(2) to a 780px so then all content within this div shows correctly. but when i am posting another list within this list the 2nd one has a width of 780px which breaks the look of it.

Comment: There are *two* elements that match `ul li:nth-child(2)`. Which one do you want to enlarge?

Comment: I suppose you did not try my suggestion in the very first comment then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this selector instead:

```
.homepage > ul > li:nth-child(2)
```

This will work for the html you have posted above, because now it will only work on a `ul` that is a direct descendent of `<div class="homepage">` and therefore not your sub `ul`.

Comment: Thank you, so i needed the > before the ul also